# Output Caching using IIS (Unable to change to No Cache)

Tags: iis, caching, browser-cache, cache-control, no-cache

Good day everyone,

I am currently having some issues with disabling my cache control to `no-cache`.
I have tried the configuring the output cache through the IIS Manager by specifying the File Name Extensions and I am not sure on how to use it properly and what to input under the Query String Variable for the User-Mode Caching. Also, I have tried configuring the web.config and it didn't work as well.. please do help me thank you!

`<staticContent> <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache"/> </staticContent>`

The URL directories that I want to disable the output cache are */arcgis_js_api/library/3.25/3.25/esri/themes/calcite/icons/fonts/CalciteWebCoreIcons.ttf* (static content)
*/arcgis/rest/services/Basemaps/Base/MapServer*

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following to web.config, the use of the `location` tag to specify which folder this applies to.

```
<configuration>
 <location path="">
   <system.webServer>
     <httpProtocol>
       <customHeaders>
         <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
       </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

If it still doesn't work, you can also refer to this article: https://www.kodyaz.com/iis-server/disable-cache-on-internet-information-services-using-output-caching.aspx.